# Parallelizing a simple loop with c++17 algorithms

Tags: c++, iterator, c++17, stl-algorithm

I have a parallel code that can be reduced to basically:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

struct TKeyObjPtr;

class TObj
{
public:
  virtual void Calculate(TKeyObjPtr const &) = 0;
};

struct TKeyObjPtr
{
  int Key;
  TObj *ObjPtr;
};

void Calculate(std::vector<TKeyObjPtr> const &KeyObjPtrVec)
{
  #pragma omp parallel for
  for (auto It1= KeyObjPtrVec.begin(); It1!=KeyObjPtrVec.end(); ++It1)
    for (auto It2= It1+1; It2!=KeyObjPtrVec.end() && It2->Key==It1->Key; ++It2)
      It1->ObjPtr->Calculate(*It2);
}
```

I would like to modernize that code by using the [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) parallel algorithms.
Unfortunately, I'm having trouble in rewriting such a simple piece of code.

An option would be using [`boost::counting_iterator`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/libs/iterator/doc/counting_iterator.html):

```
void Calculate(std::vector<TKeyObjPtr> const &KeyObjPtrVec)
{
  std::for_each(std::execution::par_unseq,
    boost::counting_iterator<std::size_t>(0u),
    boost::counting_iterator<std::size_t>(KeyObjPtrVec.size()),
    [&KeyObjPtrVec](auto i)
      {
        for (auto j= i+1; j<KeyObjPtrVec.size() && KeyObjPtrVec[j].Key==KeyObjPtrVec[i].Key; ++j)
          KeyObjPtrVec[i].ObjPtr->Calculate(KeyObjPtrVec[j]);
      });
}
```

This works but is considerably more verbose and, worse, I don't think it is compliant with the
standard because `boost::counting_iterator` is a stashing iterator and, therefore, does not
meet the [*Cpp17ForwardIterator* requirements](http://eel.is/c++draft/forward.iterators#6).

Is it possible to write the above code as concisely as with OpenMP, while satisfying the
constraints of the standard on parallel algorithms?

Comment: are you sure that `counting_iterator` is no ForwardIterator? Afaik ForwardIterator is just the minimum that is needed to make `for_each` work, not more

Comment: @user463035818 The problem is that *ForwardIterator*s are required to return a reference to some object. `counting_iterator` returns by value.

Comment: @metalfox That is not what I see on the documentation you linked. I see the `reference` typedef as being `const Incrementable&`, and `operator*` does return `reference`

Comment: I don't think this loop qualifies as "simple". The iterator pairings in `It1->ObjPtr->Calculate(*It2);` stem from consecutive `Key` values that compare equal, but only in the container part that `It1` hasn't passed yet, plus object pairings behind the iterators will be used multiple times for more than two equal consecutive keys.

Comment: @KABoissonneault Exactly `ForwardIterator`s must return a `reference` and `counting_iterator` does not. See also point 6 "*If `a` and `b` are both dereferenceable, then `a == b` if and only if `*a` and `*b` are bound to the same object*"

Comment: @user463035818 http://eel.is/c++draft/forward.iterators#1.3

Comment: @KABoissonneault ups, my standardese is really crappy, but simply not reading it is not a good excuse ;)

Comment: @lubgr `KeyObjPtrVec` is sorted by `Key`. The loop simply tests pairs of `KeyObjPtr` with equal `Key`. I don't think is complicated at all.

Comment: The fact that the vector is sorted indeed makes the loop easier to grasp. Anyway, good for you if you get what the loop is doing at first glance ;)

Answer (score 0):

If I get the algorithm right, we must

- iterate over all possible value pairs in the vector of structures, provided
  `KeyObjPtrVec` vector,
- but without pairing the object with itself
- and the order of the pair members is not important
- Then, if they `Key` field of the structure matches, we must call `Calculate` on the `Obj` field of our structure.

C++17 has the excellent built-in parallelization support, and this can simply done with the standard libraries:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <execution>

void Calculate(std::vector<TKeyObjPtr> const &KeyObjPtrVec) {
  std::vector<size_t> indices(KeyObjPtrVec.size());
  for (size_t k = 0; k < indices.size(); k++) {
    indices[k] = k;
  }

  std::for_each(std::execution::par, indices.begin(), indices.end(),
      [KeyObjPtrVec, indices](size_t k) {
        std::for_each(std::execution::par, indices.begin() + k + 1, indices.end(),
            [k, KeyObjPtrVec](size_t l) {
              if (KeyObjPtrVec[k].Key == KeyObjPtrVec[l].Key) {
                KeyObjPtrVec[k].ObjPtr->Calculate(KeyObjPtrVec[l]);
              }
            });
      });
}
```

If you specify `std::execution::par` as the first parameter of `std::for_each`, the parallel version runs. No need to care about executor, thread synchronization or any cleanup - all just works out of box. Just link the library `tbb` (`target_link_libraries(myexecutable tbb)` for cmake).

With [std::for_each](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each) you get access the element you are supposed to process, not the iterator. To get more free access required for setting up the second `std::for_each`, we create array of indices and iterate over them instead. Having index of the element, we can access the array at any relative position in the two lambdas we have.

This code is tested and confirmed to work as described in the beginning of the answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, your solution is C++17-compliant. However, it involves the materialization of the indices into a vector, which should not be necessary (also note that capturing `KeyObjPtrVec` and `indices` by value involves copying). Fortunately, the `Cpp17ForwardIterator` requirements for the parallel algorithms has been relaxed in C++23 by the adoption of [P2408R5](https://wg21.link/P2408R5), so that we will be able to use `std::ranges::iota_view` once P2408R5 is implemented in the standard library implementations.